# How can I determine what fonts a certain process is using?

Tags: fonts

A customer inquires about a scanner-panel showing the wrong font, and I want to find out which font the panel is using on a clean installation of Windows, but how am I gonna do that?

Comment: What do you mean by scanner panel?

Answer (score 1):

If you were an experienced programmer, you could trace the program in question
and see which system font calls it issues.
But then you wouldn't be posting this question.

Your other option is to identify the font that is being displayed and see
if it corresponds to the expected font.

There are many websites and tools that claim being able to identify a font
from a scanned image or screenshot. They are not all very accurate.
Unfortunately, I don't have experience with any such website or tool,
but it is easy enough to find them by asking for "font recognition"
on google.

Here is an article that discusses the issue and might help : [7 Free Tools to Identify A Font](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/7-free-tools-to-identify-a-font/).